# Servlet container Better than Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jvm, profiling

I want to know that is there any other servlet container which is better than Tomcat?
I am currently using Tomcat for my web application. It is giving good performance but not as expected. Right now I am trying to profiling tomcat using visualVM that which is there making tomcat slow. I have two  options to try:
 1) to replace tomcat with other container like web logic, etc. or
 2) try to identify problem and repair tomcat config.

Please share your views for this so that I can have an idea what to do and what not to do.

Comment: In more cases than not, your problem is going to be with your application code, or other components that are added to and running within Tomcat - not Tomcat itself.  Any problems you're facing will most likely continue to be an issue in any other servlet container you would switch to.

Comment: "It is giving good performance ... which is there making tomcat slow" -- I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run your application on JBoss, it should be easy enough to do. Said this I will recommend you to check your code first. If nothing found, try fresh installation of Tomcat, maybe your just unintentionally changed some configuration that cause you a problem.